# Angularjs ngTable with row keyboard navigation

Tags: jquery, angularjs, navigation, keyboard, ngtable

I'm trying to do the same as **Example 4 in http://nekman.github.io/keynavigator/.** The objective is to move up and down on the rows with the keyboard.

I'm using AngularJs with Bootstrap. First I tried to apply jquery as in the example but did not run ok. After that, I tried to apply angularJs using a directive over the tr element of the table and it did not work too.

**The directive code:**

```
angular.module('app').directive('navigator', function() {
    return function(scope, elem) {
      elem.keynavigator();
   }
});
```

**The table code:**

```
  <table ng-table="tableParams" template-header="ng_header" navigator class="table table-bordered table-condensed ng-table-rowselected">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="client in $data">
            <td>
                <a type="button" ng-click="edit($index)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a type="button" ng-click="delete($index)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-show="column.visible" sortable="column.field">
                    {{client[column.field]}}
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: What is not working? Do you have a exception or some unexpected behavior?

Comment: I want to navigate over table rows. When I tried with a custom angularJs directive for keynavigator I have and exception message in the console: "Uncaught cell".